# Load a file from SFTP server into spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I load a file from SFTP server into spark RDD. After loading this file I need to perform some filtering on the data. Also the file is csv file so could you please help me decide if I should use Dataframes or RDDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `spark-sftp` library in your program in following ways:

**For Spark 2.x**

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sftp_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**SBT Dependency**

```
libraryDependencies += "com.springml" % "spark-sftp_2.11" % "1.1.0"
```

**Using with Spark shell**

This package can be added to Spark using the --packages command line option. For example, to include it when starting the spark shell:

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.0
```

**Scala API**

```
// Construct Spark dataframe using file in FTP server
val df = spark.read.
            format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
            option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
            option("username", "SFTP_USER").
            option("password", "****").
            option("fileType", "csv").
            option("inferSchema", "true").
            load("/ftp/files/sample.csv")

// Write dataframe as CSV file to FTP server
df.write.
      format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
      option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
      option("username", "SFTP_USER").
      option("password", "****").
      option("fileType", "csv").
      save("/ftp/files/sample.csv")
```

**For Spark 1.x (1.5+)**

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sftp_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**SBT Dependency**

```
libraryDependencies += "com.springml" % "spark-sftp_2.10" % "1.0.2"
```

**Using with Spark shell**

This package can be added to Spark using the `--packages` command line option. For example, to include it when starting the spark shell:

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.10:1.0.2
```

**Scala API**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

// Construct Spark dataframe using file in FTP server
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.
                    format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
                    option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
                    option("username", "SFTP_USER").
                    option("password", "****").
                    option("fileType", "csv").
                    option("inferSchema", "true").
                    load("/ftp/files/sample.csv")

// Write dataframe as CSV file to FTP server
df.write().
      format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
      option("host", "SFTP_HOST").
      option("username", "SFTP_USER").
      option("password", "****").
      option("fileType", "csv").
      save("/ftp/files/sample.csv")
```

For more information on `spark-sftp` you can visit there github page [springml/spark-sftp](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp)

Comment: In `spark.read` spark is `SparkSession`, which got introduced in Spark 2.0. If you are using Spark version < 2.x, then instead of `spark` you can use `sqlContext`.

Comment: Are able to read the data ? If NO, then can you provide the full error stack trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Loading from SFTP is straight forward using the sftp-connector.

https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp

Remember it is single thread application and lands data into hdfs even you dont specify it. It Streams the data into hdfs and then creates an DataFrame on top of it

While Loading we need to specify couple of more parameters.

**Normally with out specifying the location also it may work when your user sudo user of hdfs. It will create the temp file in / of hdfs and will delete it once the process is completed.**

```
 val data = sparkSession.read.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
      option("host", "host").
      option("username", "user").
      option("password", "password").
      option("fileType", "json").
      option("createDF", "true").
      option("hdfsTempLocation","/user/currentuser/").
      load("/Home/test_mapping.json");
```

**All the available options are the following, Source code**

https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/springml/spark/sftp/DefaultSource.scala

```
override def createRelation(sqlContext: SQLContext, parameters: Map[String, String], schema: StructType) = {
    val username = parameters.get("username")
    val password = parameters.get("password")
    val pemFileLocation = parameters.get("pem")
    val pemPassphrase = parameters.get("pemPassphrase")
    val host = parameters.getOrElse("host", sys.error("SFTP Host has to be provided using 'host' option"))
    val port = parameters.get("port")
    val path = parameters.getOrElse("path", sys.error("'path' must be specified"))
    val fileType = parameters.getOrElse("fileType", sys.error("File type has to be provided using 'fileType' option"))
    val inferSchema = parameters.get("inferSchema")
    val header = parameters.getOrElse("header", "true")
    val delimiter = parameters.getOrElse("delimiter", ",")
    val createDF = parameters.getOrElse("createDF", "true")
    val copyLatest = parameters.getOrElse("copyLatest", "false")
    //System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","hdfs://devnameservice1/../")
    val tempFolder = parameters.getOrElse("tempLocation", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))
    val hdfsTemp = parameters.getOrElse("hdfsTempLocation", tempFolder)
    val cryptoKey = parameters.getOrElse("cryptoKey", null)
    val cryptoAlgorithm = parameters.getOrElse("cryptoAlgorithm", "AES")

    val supportedFileTypes = List("csv", "json", "avro", "parquet")
    if (!supportedFileTypes.contains(fileType)) {
      sys.error("fileType " + fileType + " not supported. Supported file types are " + supportedFileTypes)
    }
```

Comment: If you are using Databricks be aware of setting option("tempLocation","/tmp")

Comment: Is there a way to specify a proxy ? If no, any work-arounds ?